# The WGS84 meters-in-a-degree-of-longitude function

Tags: geolocation, gps, geocoding

I have found the meters-in-a-degree-of-latitude function, it is given [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latitude#Length_of_a_degree_of_latitude):

```
111132.954 - 559.822 * cos(2 * phi) + 1.175 * cos(4 * phi) // where phi is geodetic latitude
```

For the longitude function, the best equation I can find is that one underneath it, which is

```
pi * a * cos(phi) / (180 * sqrt(1 - e^2 * sin^2(phi)))
```

It *appears* (as shown [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longitude#Length_of_a_degree_of_longitude)) that `e` is the eccentricity of the ellipsoid, and `a` is the equatorial radius. WGS84 being the ellipsoid in question, I have both `a` and `b` so I can either [calculate `e` directly](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=a%3A%3D6378137.0%3B+b%3A%3D6356752.314245%3B+x%3Dsqrt%28%28a%5E2+-+b%5E2%29+%2F+a%5E2%29) or be [told matter-of-factly](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=wgs84+eccentricity) that it is `0.0818192`.

Now my question is simply: **is this the proper equation I should use** in order to be compatible with commonly obtained GPS angles? My understanding is that all GPS equipment nowadays (in fact, all GPS equipment **ever**) use the WGS84 geodetic latitude and longitude (where the geodetic latitude's imaginary angular line does not actually cross earth's center, but the longitude's line does), and therefore it would be silly for me to employ spherical approximation maths.

The reason for posting this question is to get a nod from somebody in this business who can verify for me that I am not in fact barking up the wrong tree or that I have made a grave error in my assumptions. In my admittedly time-strapped research conducted so far, the majority of solutions that I have seen suggested simply make use of trigonometric expressions based on spherical longitude and latitude. Although they will likely be sufficient for my needs, I refuse to employ them when I know I can obtain even more accurate values with about the same amount of work.

Answer (score 0):

No, I don't think that this is the proper formula to use:

for meters per degrees, for nearly all applications it is sufficient to just apply the factor of `cos(latitude)`, to the meters per degree at equator.

But it depends what do you want to calcuclate, why do you need the meters per degree ?
(I need that for lat/lon to cartesian transformations)
The differecne at 75° between both approaches is 90m from 28km, so for angle calculations or transformations to cartesian space this has little effect.
This all is valid if not excedeing lat 80° In polar regions >80° lat you must change all your caluclations to a polar transformation. (e.g UPS)

Comment: I am using it for transforming lat/long coordinates into a local cartesian coordinate system. I think you are right that at extreme latitudes the cartesian space will be inadequate, but I still don't see why I can't use these more accurate equations for other ordinary points on earth. Like you say a 90m difference out of 28km is about proportional to the discrepancy in the sphere approximation (the equatorial and polar radii differ by a similar ratio of 1/300). I figure I might as well take out the 1/300 error since I can.

Comment: The idea behind that, is that usually coordinates are received by GPS, which has an error of about 3-6m, if not using it at extreme latitudes. For any locale transformation the differences between two approach has no effect, since angles calculates by GPS (movingdirection), have an accuracy not more than 0.1 degrees. Best you write two such transformation methods, and compare the results, the will be in 1/1000 of a milimter.

Answer (score 0):

No.
I found an answer on StackExchange, in an article entitled Understanding terms in Length of Degree Formula.
It uses the same formula found in Wikipedia's page, Earth Radius.
The formula is in this C routine:

```
void Radii(double lat)
{
    double deg2rad = 3.141592653589793 / 180.0; // PI
    double a = 6378.1370; // radius at equator in kilometers
    double e2 = 0.0066943799901413165;
    double OneMinus_e2 = 1.0 - 0.0066943799901413165;
    double deg2radX1000 = (PI/180.0)*1000.0;

    lat *= deg2rad;
    u = 1.0-e2*sin(lat)*sin(lat);
    latmetersperdegree = (OneMinus_e2/u)*(a/sqrt(u))*deg2radX1000;
    lonmetersperdegree = cos(lat)*(a/sqrt(u))*deg2radX1000;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Well it isn't exactly rocket science (nor does that even still feel like a proper idiom considering the amount of KSP I have been playing) to just check how similar the spherical approximation is to the equation in question:

[More WolframAlpha shenanigans](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=pi+%2a+6378137.0+%2a+cos%28phi%29+%2F+%28180+%2a+sqrt%281+-+0.0818192%5E2+%2a+sin%5E2%28phi%29%29%29+vs+pi%2F180+%2a++6378137.0+%2a+cos%28phi%29)

That's enough to convince me, really...

Comment: It's a bad answer, you should post the errors measured in meters between that approaches (for some or one relevant latitude).

Comment: Hmm yeah good point. The fact that the lines are very close only indicates no enormous errors are present